# Is making a phone vibrate too often dangerous for the hardware?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, vibration

I am making an iOS app in swift using Xcode and I need the phone to vibrate to alert the user. Are there any dangers that I need to be aware of when working with vibrations or can I make the phone vibrate continuously / very frequently without problem?

Comment: Frequent vibrations will likely drain the battery quickly.  Users might not like that.

Comment: Yes, you can make phone vibrate but it'll impact the energy very high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of concerns in no particular order:

1. Power consumption
2. A vibrating phone can move when on a surface
3. Users may find this annoying and disable it or uninstall your app